# Phonegap 3.0 FileTransfer download not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm downloading a multi-part mime encoded image to iOS like this:

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
url = encodeURI(url);

ft.download(url, path, function(fileEntry) {}, function(err) {});
```

with

```
path = "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/D702F059-A29F-4FF4-A165-D4A903DEDE7D/Documents/captured/2419747919.jpeg"
```

and get the following error:

```
body: "Could not create path to save downloaded file: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)"
code: 1 (file not found)
http status: 200
```

This hints to an invalid path, but I can't see anything wrong with it. I get the path like this:

```
path = fs.root.toURL();
```

Everything else works fine and files can be stored in exactly the same path by taking photos. Just not via a FileTransfer download.

Any ideas or a bug in Phonegap 3.0? Thanks!

**UPDATE - Workaround**

FileWriter works and now even saves blobs on iOS and Android. Example code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function() {
    var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'image/jpeg'});

    // save via FileWriter
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Could you provide some code how you solved this problem? Is that a bug in Cordova? We have the same problem.

Comment: Don't know if FileTransfer works now, haven't tried in a while. See code example above. You need to know the mimeType to construct a correct blob, but that can be just text I guess. If you need a reference for the FileSystemAPI, look up Filer.js by Eric Bidelman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem in iOS:

The path:
path = "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/D702F059-A29F-4FF4-A165-D4A903DEDE7D/Documents/captured/2419747919.jpeg"

does not work because it is an URL with "localhost" in it.

From FileEntry in Cordova one can get a string using "fullPath" and "toURL" ... on Android they work both to write a file.
On iOS only the fullPath works ... the URL does not successfully write a file!

Comment: Hi @christianmenkens my i know what did you did on the success callback return to display it on image src? i got success but it returns var/mobile ...

Comment: a path with file://var/mobile/Applications/D702F059-A29F-4FF4-A165-D4A903DEDE7D/Documents/captured/2419747919.jpeg should be fine to work with on iOS. We are just using this path to put it into FileUpload.

Comment: @christianmenkens are you sure there are just two slashes after file: ? I get three when requesting FS ... (and cocoa error 512.. works well on Android)

Comment: I use dirEntry.nativeURL+filename as the target for FileTransfer.download on iOS and Android and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with that while working on the iOS Simulator, but once I tested it on the actual device, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

use nativeURL to get the prefix and append your file name to it and pass it to FileTransfer object it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `FileEntry.toURL()` to get a path that looks like this:

```
cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/file
```

See the documentation here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer